Why Goddess Jagadhatri's lion holding down an elephant on it's leg?
I saw many times that Goddess Jagadhatri's lion is holds an elephant in it's leg.

It is unknown to me that what is the reason behind that. So, my question is, Why Goddess Jagadhatri's lion is hold an elephant at it's leg? Is any scriptures mention that?

To me looks like the goddess is pictured atop a lion only, holding down an elephant head with its front left leg.

even here, the devī is on her siṁhavāhana only https://philamuseum.org/collection/object/88462 ; https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/849493 ; https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Karindrasura-Jagaddhatri.JPG The elephant head is that of an asura, who is slain by the Devī. She is not seen atop an elephant exactly, as @Narasimham said

Sorry guys, i mistook "atop", instead of "lion holded down". But, i edited it.

hmm, there are kathās, relating to the death of Gajāsura. One Gajāsura is slain by Śiva, and another is slain by Gaṇapati, who is blessed by Lalitā herself and fought in her army against asuras. I guess, the elephant head in the above photos, might represent either of the two. I am not aware of a Gajāsura, who is killed by Devī herself directly.
